# Fit scrollable body in viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

How can I fit a scrollable body within a view port?

There is a header and a footer in this table with rows. Their height is based on the components inside. But I want the body to accommodate the rest of the space so that it takes the entire height of the view port.

```js
const body = document.getElementById('body');

const createFakeData = (id) => {
  const row = document.createElement('div')
  row.innerHTML = "Row" + id;
  row.classList.add('row')
  body.appendChild(row);
}

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  createFakeData(i);
}
```

```css
.row {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  height: 100px; /*Random value, height depends on components inside*/
  background-color: yellow;
}

.body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  /*height: something; Height should take the remaining space so everything fits view port*/
}

.footer {
  height: 100px; /*Random value, height depends on components inside*/
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="body" id="body"></div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it would be a good start to not misuse the term body here. footer and header are part of the document body. what you mean is `<main>`. Also instead of using div's with an id use the correct sematic tags: `<header>`, `<main>`, and `<footer>`

Answer (score 2):

The **.container class** is set to use flexbox layout. This allows you to create a flexible container where its child elements (header, body, and footer) can be controlled in terms of their sizing and alignment.

The **.header** and **.footer** classes have fixed heights, just as in your original code.

The **.body class** uses the **flex property with a value of 1**. This means it will take up the remaining available vertical space in the container. Additionally, overflow-y: auto is added to enable vertical scrolling if the content inside the body exceeds the available space.

```js
const body = document.getElementById('body');

const createFakeData = (id) => {
  const row = document.createElement('div');
  row.innerHTML = "Row" + id;
  row.classList.add('row');
  body.appendChild(row);
};

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  createFakeData(i);
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.body {
  flex: 1; /* Take the remaining space */
  overflow-y: auto; /* Enable vertical scrolling */
}

.footer {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.row {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="body" id="body"></div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
      const appHeight = () => {
    const doc = document.documentElement
    doc.style.setProperty('--app-height', `${window.innerHeight}px`)
}
window.addEventListener('resize', appHeight)
appHeight()
    </script>  

    // add this script file inside your index.html file

.body {
  overflow-y: scroll;

  /* height:calc(var(--app-height) - headerHeight - footerHeight); */
height:calc(var(--app-height) - 100px - 100px);
}
```

Comment: why use a script for something that can be done easily at CSS level?

Comment: for some mobile devices you can't manage height with using 100vh, you need to use the value of viewport height

Comment: any proof or examples?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

1. reset the box model with `* { box-sizing: border-box }` so the elements are calculated correctly.
2. reset the default body margin with `body { margin: 0; }`
3. Use Flexbox on the body element with a flex-direction vertical by using: `body { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }`
4. Make the body fit the screen exactly by using `body { height: 100vh; }`
5. you can the main element (your id body) span the remaining space by using `main { flex-grow: 1; }`

```js
const MAIN = document.querySelector('main');

const createFakeData = (id) => {
  const ROW = document.createElement('div')
  ROW.textContent = `Row ${id}`;
  ROW.classList.add('row')
  MAIN.appendChild(ROW);
}

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  createFakeData(i);
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}



header {
  min-height: 100px; /*Random value, height depends on components inside*/
  background-color: yellow;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  /*height: something; Height should take the remaining space so everything fits view port*/
}

footer {
  min-height: 100px; /*Random value, height depends on components inside*/
  background-color: orange;
}




.row {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>Header</header>
  <main></main>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
```

PS: Use semantic tags which improves accessibility and SEO rating. Beyond that, it improves your code readability and quality.